# make: Could not find module 'System'

Tags: haskell, cabal

Yesterday I had a failing darcs install with cabal, today I get this when running ghc --make node.hs:

> node.hs:13:8:
>       Could not find module `System':
>         Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Somewhere along the lines cabal seem to have borked it's system module. What can I do to repair this?

I use version 7.0.1 of ghc on OSX.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GHC 7 uses the brand-new Haskell 2010 standard. Thus, it doesn't includes the legacy modules anymore. The recomment way is to use the new modules (like `System.IO`) instead or use the `-package haskell98` switch to enable the support again. For sure there is also a `LANGUAGE` pragma to do this.

Comment: Choosing the newer module for getArgs fixed the issue, tnx!

Comment: For those who are searching: getArgs is in System.Environment

Comment: I ran into this on darcs.  In `Distribution/ShellHarness.hs`, `system` was being imported from `System`.  To fix it, I changed the import of `system` to be from the `System.Process` module. I replaced this in the darcs tar file and then re-ran `cabal install darcs`.

Comment: What does "choosing the newer module for getArgs" mean here?  I am a newb when it comes to Haskell and don't know how to fix this error.